# WebRTC media over IOS

Tags: ios, webrtc

I want to use WebRTC's media layer with proprietary signaling on IOS. Is it possible to use only the WebRTC media layer from the ObjC library that has been released for IOS (libjingle_peerconnection_objc.a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.

- the peer connection object provides all webRTC API, which by default does not include hardware capture, media rendering, and signaling. If you want a complete solution, you will need those 3 pieces.
- appRTCDemo code (webrtc.org), provides an implementation of audio and video capturers and renderers leveraging native iOS frameworks that you can reuse out of the box.
- You could then just replace the signaling (GAE Channel) by your own. Use the signaling for the original handshake (Offer/answer) and the media/data path setup (ICE candidate exchange) and the webRTC part will be taken care of.

Comment: I have a voice based app built on top of proprietary signaling. Can I use only the webrtc voice engine separately for the audio media layer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The Voice Engine (VoE) in webRTC is handling the audio part. If you look at the source code the /webRTC subfolder is the media engine. the /talk subfolder is the peer connection part. You can also look at webRTCDemo and not appRTCDemo in the source code for an executable that leverage only the media components. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace media part only in your proprietary solution you can use VoiceEngine from WebRTC.

It's a part of webrtc's core and peer connection api is built on top of this. You should be aware that at your disposal will be RTP sender/receiver + voice processing. Security layer, NAT traversal, etc should be implemented by yourself.